# How can I use Google translator fixed in my header instead of in the bottom?

Tags: html, css, header, google-translate

I am using some code from google translator that I found somewhere, but the choice menu button appears always fixed in the bottom, despite I add the code to the header of my page. I am believe it is something in css that is forcing this behaviour. Since I am not a css specialist I can't say what is it. Maybe someone can help me.

> @translate-bg: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important; @translate-border:
> black !important; @downicon-color:red; @langicon-color:blue;
> @translate-text-color:black; @translate-font:sans-serif;
>
> #google_translate_element {   z-index: 100;   border-radius: 0;   right: 2vw;   left: auto;   position: fixed;   bottom: 1vh; }
>
> .goog-te-gadget-simple {   background-color: @translate-bg !important;
> border-color:@translate-border !important;   padding: 0.2em
> !important;   border-radius: 4px !important;   font-size: 1rem
> !important;   line-height: 2rem !important;   display: inline-block;
> cursor: pointer;   } .goog-te-menu2 {   max-width: 100%; }
> .goog-te-menu-value {   display: flex;   align-items: center;   color:
> #fff; } .goog-te-menu-value:before {   content: "\e894";   margin-right: 0.5em;  font-family: 'Material Icons';
> color:@langicon-color; } .goog-te-menu-value span {
> color:@translate-text-color;   font-family:@translate-font; }
> .goog-te-menu-value span:nth-child(1) {   position: relative;   top:
> 0.07rem; }
>
> .goog-te-menu-value span:nth-child(5) {   display: none; }
> .goog-te-menu-value span:nth-child(3) {   border: none !important;
> font-family: 'Material Icons';   display: flex;    }
> .goog-te-menu-value span:nth-child(3):after {   font-family: 'Material
> Icons';   content: "\E5C5";   font-size: 1.5rem;
> color:@downicon-color !important; } .goog-te-gadget-icon {   display:
> none; } .goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {   display:
> none!important; }
>
> body {   top: 0px !important; }
>
> var GoogleLanguages = 'en,pt,fr,it,es';

src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">

> function googleTranslateElementInit() {   new
> google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en',
> includedLanguages: GoogleLanguages, layout:
> google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay:
> false}, 'google_translate_element'); }  src="https://storage.googleapis.com/squarestylist/translate-style.js">